# Data structure that has O(n) iteration, O(1) contains and O(1) get by key

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I'm looking for a data-structure, or combination of several, that can give me a behaviour that satisfies these conditions:

1. O(n) Iteration (does not have to be in-order)
2. O(1) Contains
3. O(1) Get (by key, which is an int)
4. O(1) Add
5. O(1) Remove

The three solutions I've come up with is something like this, which both are just uses of the built in collections in .NET

1. Build my own hash set which exposes more of the internal storage to the outside world then the default `HashSet<T`> in .NET
2. Use an `Dictionary<int, T>`, as the iteration does not have to be in-order, but this is a very high performance application and the garbage that gets generated by creating the enumerator each time I need to step through the collection worries me. The worrying about garbage is not one I "made up", this is for a real time simulation and any garbage that could trigger a GC basically a non-option if it can be avoided.
3. Use a combination of a `Dictionary<int, int>` and a `T[]`, basically store the key + index into the array in the dictionary, and store the elements in the `T[]`.

Comment: If you that worried about GC you should not be using C# in the first place

Comment: re your point about garbage; there isn't much internally different between a `Dictionary<int,int>` and a `Dictionary<int, T>`

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I dispute that; it is perfectly possible to use C# and be aware of GC impact, and code accordingly.

Comment: Just use a `HashSet<>` (it has O(1) for Add and for Contains) and start optimizing when you can really pinpoint a problem.

Comment: Have you tried option 2? It seems like the cleanest / easiest to implement one, and probably you will not notice any issues.

Comment: If you want to avoid garbage buildup, use the `using` construct to reclaim memory as soon as possible

Comment: @MarcGravell it is, if i don't iterate over the `Dictionary<int, int>` and only the `T[]`.

Comment: @dario_ramos: Using `using` doesn't help reclaim memory in any way; that's handled by the GC and is completely orthogonal to whether the type was disposed etc.

Comment: @thr: An enumerator is a very tiny piece of memory, hard to write anything in C# that doesn't produce a lot more 'garbage'. And cleaning out (very many) gen-0 objects is O(1) too. Don't solve problems you don't have.

Comment: @LukeH: If you make `T` implement IDisposable, it's freed at the end of the using block. The usual implementation of the Dispose Pattern implies calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`, so the GC no longer cares about the disposed object

Comment: As always when dealing with such strong performance requirements, theory is a bad friend. I'd better wrote some close-to-life tests and carried out experiments with all possible structures to see what the truth is. It is also important to take CLR settings into account (various memory limits, etc). It may occur that some structures are better with these settings while other structures win with those ones.

Comment: @dario_ramos: It's not "freed" at the end of the `using` block (if by "freed" you mean "its memory is reclaimed"). The `using` block simply ensures that `Dispose` is called. The memory will be reclaimed at some point *after* the object is no longer referenced, regardless of whether it was disposed.

Comment: @dario_ramos You are wrong. `SuppressFinalize` means the object is removed from the finalization queue and its finalizer is not called. However, it does not mean that the memory is freed once the method is called. Freeing memory is a separate process of the `GC`.

Comment: @thr, @Henk: The enumerators returned by `Dictionary<K,V>.GetEnumerator`, `Dictionary<K,V>.Keys.GetEnumerator` and `Dictionary<K,V>.Values.GetEnumerator` are all structs anyway, so there's possibly no GC cost whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a generic [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) that allows objects to be indexed by an int and a key. The key must be embeded in the value.

You can use a for(int i...) to iterate over it without an IEnumerable.